# Custom Keras Loss Function with Internal Prediction

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras

I'm in the process of creating an obfuscation neural network using Keras that will distort an image before being fed into a trained classification neural network. In order to do so, I need to generate a loss based on the value produced by the classification network.

I have created a loss function that feeds the distorted image as `y_pred`, and the classification labels as `y_true`.

```
class_model = load_model(model_path)

def classfication_error(self, y_true, y_pred):
    y_pred = class_model.predict(y_pred)
    return keras.losses.categorical_crossentropy(y_true, y_pred)
```

When compiling the model, I receive the following error due to the shape of `y_pred = (?, 32, 32, 3)`

```
ValueError: When feeding symbolic tensors to a model, we expect thetensors to have a static batch size. Got tensor with shape: (None, 32, 32, 3)
```

What would be another way to accomplish the prediction within the loss function as to avoid the error?